# In a 2D complex vector space, are there more than 3 orthonormal bases that are all "45 degrees" from each other?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, complex-numbers

If I understand correctly, if a quantum spin is measured/prepared in the $+x$ direction, then there is a .5 probability of subsequently measuring it in the $+y$ direction and .5 probability of measuring it in the $-y$ direction. This is because

$$| \langle y+|x+ \rangle| = | \langle y-|x+ \rangle| = 1/\sqrt{2},$$

i.e. the $y$ eigenstates are each at a "45 degree" angle to each of the $x$ eigenstates. By symmetry this is true for the $z$ vs $x$ case and the $z$ vs $y$ case also.

One can see this by choosing a basis where

$$|x+\rangle = [1, 0]^*, |x-\rangle = [0, 1]^*$$

$$|y+\rangle = [1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}]^*, |y-\rangle = [1/\sqrt{2}, -1/\sqrt{2}]^*$$

$$|z+\rangle = [1/\sqrt{2}, -i/\sqrt{2}]^*, |z-\rangle = [1/\sqrt{2}, i/\sqrt{2}]^*$$

and computing the inner products to show each basis is orthonormal and is "rotated 45 degrees" from each of the others.

My question is: can one find a fourth orthonormal basis $\{|w+ \rangle, |w- \rangle\}$ that is itself 45 degrees from each of the other three? Intuitively it seems like there are too many constraints for this to be possible, but I'm having a hard time visualizing or calculating exactly why.

If this is indeed impossible, is there a deeper relationship between the 2D complex vector space in which spin is introduced in QM and the 3 dimensions of ordinary space? Is the 2D nature of QM spin states somehow derivable from the symmetry of space?

If we lived in $k$-dimensional ordinary physical space, what dimension complex vector space would QM spin states live in?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to find a fourth set.  Your question is related to the existence of [mutually unbiased bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_unbiased_bases).  In your case, this problem is one of finding sets of pairs of states like $\vert x,\pm\rangle$ etc so that any overlap between elements in different sets satisfies
$$
\vert \langle y;\pm\vert x\pm\rangle\vert^2=\frac{1}{2} \qquad \hbox{etc.}
$$
In dimension 2 it is know there are only 3 sets and they are the ones you listed.  They are eigenvectors of $\sigma_x,\sigma_y$ and $\sigma_z$ respectively.

In dimension $k$, where $k$ is a prime or power of a prime, it is known that one can construct $k+1$ sets, where in each sets there are $k-1$ commuting operators, and the common eigenvectors of these $k-1$ commuting operators will be orthogonal and satisfy $\vert \langle \alpha,j\vert \beta,m\rangle \vert^2=1/k$, where $\alpha$ labels a set and $j$ an eigenvector in this set.  For $k=2$, you have three sets each containing one operator:
$\{\sigma_x\}, \{\sigma_y\},\{\sigma_z\}$.

If the dimension $k=p^n$ is a power of a prime, one must use the algebraic field extension of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, but it is possible to find $k+1$ sets each containing $k-1$ vectors to satisfy the condition that the modulus squared of the overlap is $1/k$.

If $k$ is a composite number (like $6=2\times 3$), it is not known if one can find the complete collection of $k+1$ sets of $k-1$ vectors.  In fact it is conjectured that one cannot, and extensive numerical work has been done in dimension $6$ (by Brierley and Weigert, see [this arXiv post](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.4051)), since this is the lowest composite number.

MUB have applications in foundational physics, in quantum tomoagraphy, and in state reconstruction.  They are also linked to Latin squares (see for instance [this arXiv post](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.6742) or [this arXiv post](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0407081); a GoogleScholar search returns more hits), which are themselves linked to algebraic field theory (not the fields as in E&M field, but fields in the [in the mathematical sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20field%20is,many%20other%20areas%20of%20mathematics.)).

Comment: Thanks, fascinating! I had no idea prime numbers would be involved in the answer.